# Hibernate - @OneToOne mappedBy one of multiple class fields

Tags: java, hibernate

I have class hierarchy like this:

```
public abstract class CommunicationCampaign {...}
public class EmailCampaign extends CommunicationCampaign {...}
public class SmsCampaign extends CommunicationCampaign {...}
public class Trigger {...}
```

*CommunicationCampaign* defines what kind of message should be distribute to our clients and *Trigger* defines when communication should be distributed. Campaign should point to two triggers, test trigger and production trigger. The code for this look like this:

```
public abstract class CommunicationCampaign {
...
@OneToOne(targetEntity = Trigger.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "TEST_TRIGGER_ID")
private Trigger testTrigger;
@OneToOne(targetEntity = Trigger.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "TRIGGER_ID")
private Trigger trigger;
...
}
```

**My question is how should i map this relation on the *Trigger* side**? This is the first time I'm facing such problem, so I would appreciate any advice. Maybe I shouldn't approach this using *@OneToOne* mapping, however I would like to avoid solution with *@OneToMany* mapping, because then I would have to add new column to *Trigger* indicating if it is test trigger or not. Trigger behavior should be exactly the same regardless it is used as test or regular trigger for specific campaign. Also Trigger is related to other entities in database and I want to do as little modification as possible to it.

```
public class Trigger {
...
/*How to map relation to SmsCampaign and EmailCampaign?*/
...
}
```

I'm looking for something like this:

```
public class Trigger {
...
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "testTrigger or trigger", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private EmailCampaign emailCampaign;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "testTrigger or trigger", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private SmsCampaign smsCampaign;
...
}
```

Comment: Does your trigger need to know to which campaign it's connected? But just to get things clear your `EmailCampaign` and `SmsCampaign` each only use one of those trigger or do both of them use both triggers? That's not quite clear.

Comment: @kaba713, yes, trigger needs to know to which campaign it's connected. Each campaign can have up to two triggers, one for testing and one for production. None of this triggers is obligatory, we can define campaign so that it will never be triggered. On the other hand, trigger can invoke only one campaign. It doesn't matter if it is test or production trigger the behavior is the same, if trigger conditions are fulfilled then campaign will be invoked. So I would say this is OneToTwo relation (one campaign [e-mail or sms] and up to two triggers).

Comment: @kaba713, small correction to my last comment. In database trigger can reference one of each, e-mail and sms. However I will be validating that on java level so that trigger will have only one campaign. What is validated on DB lvl: Any campaign can have up to two triggers. One for testing and one for production, also trigger for production and testing can't be the same.